# nextjs-ts-user-management, how to handle redirect to login page using @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs?

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase, nextjs-dynamic-routing

**TLDR:**
I'm leveraging https://github.com/supabase/supabase/tree/master/examples/user-management/nextjs-ts-user-management
to build basically a TODO/hello world app and it's amazing. But you will notice that the way they handle loginpage/protected pages toggle in nextjs-ts-user-management is via `session ? <Account/>: <Login/>` ([here](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/examples/user-management/nextjs-ts-user-management/pages/index.tsx#L13)) which is not compatible with using Next's file directory routing system and therefore doesn't allow me to use `router` etc. Is there an example somewhere that shows how to do this the correct way using urls?

**Details:**
I have successfully implemented a `middleware.ts` to redirect the user to login page if they're not authenticated per the instructions here which works great! https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#auth-with-nextjs-middleware
but it only works when user tries to navigate to a new page.

The middleware.ts does not redirect the user for the below situations:

1. user clicks a signOut button
2. user revisits the page after he is no longer authenticated

Is there some best practice way of addressing those 2 situations since it doesnt seem possible to do using middleware?

I've tried making "ProtectedRoutes" and stuff like that but it has 2 problems (1.no way to see if session is loading so login page flashes on page load, 2. it doesnt actually change the url, they are still on /profile but seeing the login page for example.)

After some digging I found this [NextJS + Supabase - Blank Page Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74116700/nextjs-supabase-blank-page-issue)
but it still doesn't solve the "doesnt change the url" problem i listed above.

Any help or pointers is appreciated. I'm pretty new to Next and I love it, surely i am missing something simple here...

here is what I have currently:

```
"@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs": "^0.5.2",
"@supabase/auth-helpers-react": "^0.3.1",
"@supabase/auth-ui-react": "^0.2.2",
"@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.0.4",
"next": "12.3.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0"
```

```
//_app.tsx


function MyApp({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<{
  initialSession: Session
}>) {
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient())
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <RouteGuard>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </RouteGuard>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </SessionContextProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp

const RouteGuard = ({ children }: { children: ReactElement }) => {
  const session = useSession()
  const { user, isAuthorizing } = useAuth()
  if (isAuthorizing) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  if (!session) {
    return <Login />
  }
  return <>{children}</>
}
```

```
//useAuth.js

import { useSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [isAuthorizing, setIsAuthorizing] = useState(true)
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient()
  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth
      .getUser()
      .then((response) => {
        setUser(response.data.user)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsAuthorizing(false)
      })
  }, [])

  return { user, isAuthorizing }
}
```

```
//login.tsx

import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { Auth, ThemeSupa, ThemeMinimal } from '@supabase/auth-ui-react'
import { useSession, useSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { Layout } from '../components/Layout'
import { LayoutTailwind } from '../components/LayoutTailwind'
import { CodeBracketIcon, TvIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'
import { CurrencyDollarIcon, LifebuoyIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export const Login: NextPage = () => {
  const session = useSession()
  const router = useRouter()
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient()

  if (session) {
    router.push('/posts')
  }

  return (
    <div className="mt-12">
      <div className="flex min-h-full">
        <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-sm lg:w-96">
          <div>
            <CodeBracketIcon className="h-12" />
            <h2 className="mt-6 text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">Code Market</h2>
            <div className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600 ">
              <div className="flex items-center pb-1 gap-1">
                <LifebuoyIcon className="h-4" />
                Offer money for coding help
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                <CurrencyDollarIcon className="h-4" />
                Make money helping other coders
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="mt-8">
            <Auth
              providers={['github']}
              supabaseClient={supabase}
              appearance={{ theme: ThemeMinimal }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* <Footer /> */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
//middleware.ts

import { createMiddlewareSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // We need to create a response and hand it to the supabase client to be able to modify the response headers.
  const res = NextResponse.next()
  // Create authenticated Supabase Client.
  const supabase = createMiddlewareSupabaseClient({ req, res })
  // Check if we have a session
  const {
    data: { session },
  } = await supabase.auth.getSession()

  // return res
  // Check auth condition
  if (session?.user.id) {
    // Authentication successful, forward request to protected route.
    return res
  }

  // Auth condition not met, redirect to home page.
  const redirectUrl = req.nextUrl.clone()
  redirectUrl.pathname = '/'
  // redirectUrl.searchParams.set(`redirectedFrom`, req.nextUrl.pathname)
  return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl)
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/posts', '/createpost', '/profile'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this ended up being the solution:
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs-server-components#supabase-listener

you should just look at the link above, but in case that goes away:

```
'use client'

import { useSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function SupabaseListener({ accessToken }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient()
  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      if (session?.access_token !== accessToken) {
        router.reload()
      }
    })
  }, [accessToken])

  return null
}
```

then you just put this somewhere high in your stack:

```
<SupabaseListener accessToken={session?.access_token} />
```

now whenever logged in status changes it refreshes the page which will then trigger your middleware.ts file to redirect you to login page

Answer (score 0):

Well currently Supabase worked as server functions, now we no longer need to declare the SessionContextProvider, (https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#middleware) and the new functions are already supported working middlewares and server functions too... Try using a ready-made template that comes with some ready-to-use examples using a new project and with better performance and security improvements that are described in the docs... Use `npx create-next-app -e with-subase` to create a ready-made project template and start using it very easily... Hope I helped :)